# Equivalient function for adding _source to SearchQueryBuilder in Elasticsearch Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using the following search query:

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.getClient()
                .prepareSearch("index_5589b14f3004fb6be70e4724")
                .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
                .setQuery(QueryStem(stem))
                .addFields("field1", "field2")
                .setHighlighterPostTags("</em>")
                .setHighlighterPreTags("<em>")
                .addHighlightedField("field1", 20, 150)
                .addHighlightedField("field2", 20, 150)
                .setFrom(1)
                .setSize(1);
```

The equivalent version of the DSL is:

```
GET index_5589b14f3004fb6be70e4724/document_set/_search
{
  "query": {
       // some query
  },
  "fields": ["field1", "field2"],
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags" : ["<em>"],
    "post_tags" : ["</em>"],
    "fields": {
      "field1": {
        "number_of_fragments": 10,
        "fragment_size": 20
      },
      "field2": {
        "number_of_fragments": 10,
        "fragment_size": 20
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried `.getSource()` in the Search response but it gave me the `NullPointerException`. Then I checked on Sense and found that it does not have any `_source` field. But if I add `"_source": [...],` to the Query DSL I get the required data I want.

I want to add `"_source": ["docset_id", "doc_id"],` to the `SearchRequestBuilder`. How should I do it? I was thinking of using `.setSource()` but it does something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `.setFetchSource(@Nullable String[] include, @Nullable String[] exclude)` method to signify which fields you'd like to return, so in your case:

```
.setFetchSource(new String[]{"docset_id", "doc_id"}, null)
```