# How to convert (Elastic Search query) in to java efficiently?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I get the results well by typing the below code in kibana(Elastic Search). Can someone please show me how to do the exact smaething from java?. All i want to do is extract the "comments" parts of the objects and add it into a string array.

```
 GET local_rs_4_0_0_*/review/_search
{
"_source": ["comment"],
"query": {
"bool": {

  }
 }
}


{
"took": 4,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 3,
"successful": 3,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 2,
"max_score": 1,
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "local_rs_4_0_0_app_reviewspotter_1552993787904",
    "_type": "review",
    "_id": "r_anuradhapura_1552994866938",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "comment": "Test Comment"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "local_rs_4_0_0_app_reviewspotter_1552993787904",
    "_type": "review",
    "_id": "r_anuradhapura_1552994964151",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "comment": "Test"
    }
  }
 ]
}
}
```

Comment: By convert it to Java,  do you mean create Java client code that does equivalent of this search call ? if so Jest client also takes this form of query. do you really need to convert it.

Comment: I have a java backed and I only need to retrieve the comments part in the above data from the back end and add it in to a string array!  (please check the question, i added the result from the above query as well)

Comment: You need a java client for this. You can use [Java High Level REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html), elasticsearch own java based client.

Comment: I found somewhat close answer to this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632353/equivalient-function-for-adding-source-to-searchquerybuilder-in-elasticsearch-j Can someone help with posting the whole method body in this answer? It will be a breat help to many.